# Alloting a read replica to a particular app in Django?

Tags: django, django-database

The django project has multiple apps and they all right now access the same DB. If I want one app which has only read queries to read from read replica will I have to add routers for both DB or creating one router for read replica and alloting it to the app will work? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I want to use the replica for an entire app for all the operations, while other apps keep using the default db., which is not looking possible through routers.

Answer (score -1):

you can use multiple database as defined in documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/

Ex:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password1'
    },
    'read_replica': {
        'NAME': 'customer_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_cust',
        'PASSWORD': 'password2'
    } 
}
```

After use a Database Router (django.db.router):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers
There is a DATABASE_ROUTERS config as well.

Comment: Please read the question. I want to use the replica for an entire app for all the operations, while other apps keep using the default db., which is not looking possible through routers.